# CLLocation timestamp is wrong [In the past]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have an issue with CLLocation timestamp after activating airplaneMode.
System notifies my application by an old position with wrong timestamp.
- last night I was at the place X
- I turned my device to airplane mode. and I traveled to place you.
- Today morning I disabled the airplane mode.
- Issue: system returns a location to location of place X and time stamp of today morning.
Do you found this issue before and how to solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just ignore locations with out-of-date timestamps.

Comment: The initial location fix can be inaccurate (very inaccurate in the scenario you describe). The problem is the device doesn't know that it has moved until it works out that it has moved, so it sends the last location that it had. You can use the `horizontalAccuracy` of the location update to decide whether you should use or ignore the update.